# How to display a table of items once I select a value from the first dropdownlist using MVC 4 jQuery and AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

//Hi so Im building an MVC4 project where I have a list of programs and each program is tied to a list of Outlets, Im trying to display a table of Outlets once the user select a program from my dropdownlist , so far I have a jQuery function which fires whenever the selection changes and I am able to retrieve the program id for it .. great , but how do I make an ajax call to populate a table with the associated outlets to that program

I have a partial View which is in charge of drawing my outlet table , 
All I need to do is from my jQuery function make an ajax call to a function in my controller and pass the programid which in this case is `var $input = $(this).find('option:selected').val();`

Controller

```
 public ActionResult AddOutletFromExisting()
    {
        int selectedValue = 0;

        ViewBag.Programs = new SelectList(new ProgramRepository().GetPrograms(), "ProgramID", "ProgramName", selectedValue);
        return View();
    }
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddOutletFromExisting(FormCollection collection, int selectedValue=0)
    {
        var outlets = new OutletRepository().GetStoresByProgram(selectedValue).ToPagedList(1, 10);
        return PartialView("_Outlets", outlets);
    }
```

View

```
    @Html.DropDownList("ProgramID", (SelectList)ViewBag.Programs, string.Empty, new { id="dropdown" })
```

jQuery

```
$("#dropdown").change(function () {
    var $input = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    //call a function in my controller and pass $input to this function
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to filter the grid based on dropdown value, right?
You have to follow the below steps for that.

1. Create a controller action, which filter the result based on the parameter(which will come from ajax call-you'll see in the next step)
2. Create the view for this action. It'll contain the code for table
3. Call the action method using jQuery ajax/post method
4. Update the grid content

Here is the [link-Filtering a Grid of Data in ASP.NET MVC](https://web.archive.org/web/20210306172725/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011911-1.aspx) which explains with example

**UPDATE**

```
$("#dropdown").change(function () {
    var selectedValue = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    //call a function in my controller and pass $input to this function
    $.ajax({
       url:"/Controller/GridFilterActionMethod",
       type: "POST",
       data: { selectedValue: selectedValue },
       success:function(result){
           $("#div1").html(result); //here, div1 would be your grid-div id
       }
    });
});
```

As per the above code, your action method parameter name should be `selectedValue`-should match with the json object name.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion and that is exactly how I approached it, I updated my question

Comment: @user2599836: please show your filter action method for more clarification, if this doesn't solve your problem

Comment: thanks for your follow up I appreciate it, see the updated question

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to do an ajax call to the server and retrieve the HTML for the list of outlets. Then simply append the list to an element on the page:

```
$("#dropdown").change(function () {
    var $input = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    $.get('/outlets/' + input, function(data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
    });
});
```

Another solution would be that instead of the action method returning HTML, it would return JSON. In such a case you would bind to a template that you define. This is a bit more complicated, but allows the action method to simply focus on returning data and not worry with the rendering.

Comment: I updated my question hopefully its more clear of what I want to do :(